# make nerdtree buffer consistent

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

I like how nerdtree looks as a side-drawer.

[image]
but if I close current buffer using `:bd`

nerdtree will become a fullscreen buffer

[image]
and all new buffers will simply take full screen, nerdtree won't toggle as drawer but as full screen all the time, untull its closed and reopened

[image]

is there any way to make nerdtree consistently open as a drawer and never go full screen?

Comment: This is clearly not the answer you're looking for but I've been struggling with NERDTree a long time before I realized that it is not worth the trouble. You might be interested in [this article](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) which explains pretty well why using NERDTree is not a good idea. NERDTree has several inconsistent behaviors which (IMO) make it unusable. If netrw is not good enough for you I would suggest that you have a look at [dirvish](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-dirvish) which is a decent directory viewer.

Comment: @statox I fear your absolutely right. NERDTree just works on my nerves atm.

Comment: Then it might be the moment to let it go ;) Honestly I was afraid to ditch nerdtree but then I realized that with all of the built-in facilities (netrw, `:e`, `:find`, `:vimgrep`, ...) and the available external tools (Once I got used to [ctrlp](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) my life changed) you really don't need a buggy/anti-vim-way plugin like NERDtree. But this conversation is becoming off topic for the question so I hope someone can help you. Also you should check [nerdtree's issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues) maybe you'll get an answer there.

Comment: Nerdtree is a good starter to get productive in vim as beginner. But it absolutly breaks all split related stuff. Once familiar with vim, you should get rid of it (in my opinion at least). I use https://github.com/tpope/vim-vinegar

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo one good use of nerdtree is having tree next to you while working, so you don't keep the proj tree in your head all the time.

Comment: @salivan yes that is true, and i guess it is also one of the advantages of working with rails, you know the tree anyway. But Nerdtree is really bad with splits, and with vinegar you are really fast back at the project drawer. And you could also leave the vinegar split open to see the project. But I see why you want Nerdtree. But i bet you wouldn't miss it once you've worked a few days without =)

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I've removed it, and trying to work with `netrw` lets see how it goes :)

Comment: @salivan nice =) i still suggest vinegar which is an ehanced version of netrw. But if you don't want that, i would map newtr to a single button (in vinegar its " - ") so you are fast in the filebrowser.

Comment: I'm new to using Vim myself and have found Nerdtree to be quite useful. I have it bound to F3 where I can toggle it at times where I quickly need to see the project file structure. The CtrlP plugin has already been mentioned and I absolutely recommend that if you want to track down certain files. I would also suggest, although it's somewhat off topic, using Tmux as a means to separate Vim alongside other terminal panes so you can swap between and run grep commands, do Git actions and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Some related posts are posted [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/400) and [here](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/issues/460). Basically if you use `bd`, vim will close the window the current buffer is in, causing Nerdtree window to take the whole screen. The simple mapping below prevent the window from closing after using `bd`:

```
nnoremap \d :bp<cr>:bd #<cr>
```

Feel free to change the mapped key as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

With focus on `NERDTree`, type `A`. Then open some file from `NERDTree` and it will open correctly.

Comment: I don't have NERDTree installed, but from reading the documentation this looks like it could work (`A` "zooms" or "minimises/maximises" NERDTree). This answer could benefit from a bit more explanation of why it does, though.

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes.

Instead of using `:NERDTreeToggle`, use `:NERDTree`. This will use the default settings of the window size to open a new `NERDTRee` window.